# How to run a cron job in aws for node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to run a Cronjob in AWS (EC2). My crontab file looks like this
1 * * * * node /var/apps/project-name/file.js

This is supposed to trigger my file.js every 1 minute but it is not happening. Can someone help me where I am wrong?

Pls Comment if more details are needed

Comment: What's in the logs?

Comment: @kichik after saving the crontab, no logs are produced

Comment: Try `grep -rs CRON /var/log`. It should be `syslog` IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is few options:

1. Your cron user (who executes cron) have no permissions on file

To fix this, you can add permissions to execute with this command `sudo chmod 755 /var/apps/project-name/file.js`

2. Cron user can't find `node`, so you need to specify full path. 

To find your node.js on server, run `which node` and than add it to cron file
Like this:
`0 * * * * /usr/bin/node /var/apps/project-name/file.js`

Comment: It was the path.. Thanks